# How to exclude tags and categories from a function?

Tags: php

I'm trying to get a piece of code to filter out tags and categories when it generates its list. Right now it generates all posts by most recent (although it's a little buggy so if someone knows a better piece of code to use with ajax load more, I'm all ears.

Here's the code:

```
<div class="mcol-posts ajax-posts">
  <?php
    //BLOG POSTS
      $postsPerPage = 5;
      $args = array(
      'posts_per_page' => $postsPerPage
      $loop = new WP_Query($args);
      while ($loop->have_posts()) : $loop->the_post(); 
      get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', 'excerpt' );
      endwhile;
      wp_reset_postdata();                          
   ?>
</div>
```

I want to add something like this (could be different, but this is what I'm working with right now), in order to exclude any posts with tags or categories I don't want. It would be ideal to exclude more than one tag and more than one category, or to NULL either/both if not needed.

```
if ($cat_not_in) {
  $args['category__not_in'] = array($cat_not_in);
}
if ($tag_not_in) {
  $args['tag__not_in'] = array($tag_not_in);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how the structure of `$cat_not_in` looks like but make sure that that variable is not an array. If `$cat_not_in` is an array then you could try

```
if ($cat_not_in) {
  $args['category__not_in'] = $cat_not_in;
}
if ($tag_not_in) {
  $args['tag__not_in'] = $tag_not_in;
}
```

Also see [WP Codex - WP_Query](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Category_Parameters) it allows for category exclusion by prefixing the category ID with a `- (minus)`. Worth a try too. SO if your building your `$cat_not_in` array you could just prefix the IDs with `-` and then

```
if ($cat_not_in) {
  $args['cat'] = $cat_not_in;
}
```

Another approach completely might be to get a list of all category IDs into a `$cat_get` array and then iterate through the `$cat_not_in` array or string and pop the IDs you don't want off the `$cat_get` array then you can use the same code as above like this

```
if ($cat_not_in) {
  $args['cat'] = $cat_get;
}
```